# Why using new when reporting an exception in php

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

In php , why it is used "new" when reporting an exception since we do not need a variable cause action is already being concluded. This is a code i found when learning exception handling. I am having trouble understanding this.

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
```

Can't we use

```
throw Exception('Division by zero.');
```

Comment: This is not a question for SO. It's a very basic stuff that you can learn simply searching on google where you will find tons of courses and tutorial about this and much other. Remember php.net your bible.

Comment: Keep in mind that "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__", "**non-programming-related**" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Exception is an instance of the Exception class. If there is no instance of this class already created, then we have to create it. Since Errors are handled through non-static classes, we can't use it as a static method.